# Tkinter window menu root issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So i'm creating a chat bot inside of a tkinter gui but keep getting an error message when creating the main menu and sub menu. Any help is appreciated. Here's the code:

```
    # Open the window 
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Newton")
    root.geometry("400x500")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    
    # Chat window menu settings
    main_menu=Menu(root)
    file_menu=Menu(root)
    
    # Add commands to submenu
    file_menu.add_command(label="New..")
    file_menu.add_command(label="Save As..")
    file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")
    main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", Menu=file_menu)
    
    # Add the rest of the menu options to the main menu
    main_menu.add_command(label="Edit")
    main_menu.add_command(label="Quit")
    root.config(Menu=main_menu)
```

The error I'm getting is:
main_menu=Menu(root)
NameError:'Menu' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is `import tkinter as tk`. So you need to suffix every item imported from the module with `tk`, like:

```
# Chat window menu settings
main_menu = tk.Menu(root) # Just like root = tk.Tk()
file_menu = tk.Menu(root)
```

Also one more thing I noticed:

```
root.config(menu=main_menu) # Instead of Menu=main_menu
```